# now-cli deployment doesn't build package.json dependencies

Tags: node.js, serverless, svelte, vercel, sapper

I'm trying to deploy a Sapper built application via 
`@now-node`. The task is basically to deploy a Polka server with dependencies and to serve static/ and client/ files statically. I have managed to include the files that Lambda requires via includeFiles but now I see in the logs that the builder ignores dependencies described in package.json. The exact message is

```
Starting server on port 3000
Cannot find module 'sirv'
Did you forget to add it to "dependencies" in `package.json`?
```

But I see in the build log that dependencies are not collected. Both `package.json` and `package-lock.json` are present in the source files.

I'd appreciate any advice on how to approach this.

The now.json config I arrived at looks like this:

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "name": "experimental-sapper",
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "__sapper__/build/index.js",
            "use": "@now/node",
            "config": {
                "includeFiles": [
                    "../build/**",
                    "../../static/**"
                    ]
            }
        },
        {
            "src": "static/**",
            "use": "@now/static"
        },
        {
            "src": "__sapper__/build/client/**",
            "use": "@now/static"
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        { "src": "/(.*(\\.css)|(\\.json)|(\\.png))", "dest": "/static/$1" },
        { "src": "/client/(.*)", "dest": "/__sapper__/build/client/$1" },
        { "src": "/(.*)", "dest": "/__sapper__/build/index.js" }
    ],
    "alias": "..."
}
```

And the src/server.js looks like this (before Rollup bundling):

```
import sirv from 'sirv';
import polka from 'polka';
import compression from 'compression';
import * as sapper from '@sapper/server';
const { PORT, NODE_ENV } = process.env;
const dev = NODE_ENV === 'development';
const app = polka() // You can also use Express
    .use(compression({ threshold: 0 }));
if (dev) {
    app.use(sirv('static', { dev }));
}
app.use(sapper.middleware())
    .listen(PORT, err => {
        if (err) console.log('error', err);
    });
export default app.handler;
```

Then package.json is pretty standard as well:

```
  "description": "TODO",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "sapper dev",
    "build": "sapper build --legacy",
    "export": "sapper export --legacy",
    "start": "node __sapper__/build",
    "cy:run": "cypress run",
    "cy:open": "cypress open",
    "test": "run-p --race dev cy:run"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "compression": "^1.7.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "polka": "^0.5.0",
    "postcss-define-property": "^0.5.0",
    "sirv": "^0.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "browserslist": "last 2 versions"
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Now looks for the package-lock.json file which locks down the dependencies. Make sure that you always run `npm install` after adding a new dependency. Try to remove the lockfile and recreate it using npm install. Then commit your changes.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that now looks for the package.json file in the folder that contains the endpoint, not in the deployment root. Can this be correct @TomScholz?

Comment: I found in order to publish my Sapper App to now, I had to change the package.json build script to "build": "sapper export --legacy". Once I did that, everything uploaded as expected. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody coming across this question, the solution is to use the `now-sapper` builder at https://www.npmjs.com/package/now-sapper

There are instructions on the site, but essentially you need to export your handler as mentioned above, then let the builder do the rest. There are a few intricacies to now which mean that the node builder alone won't work.

Your now configuration should look like:

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "package.json",
      "use": "now-sapper"
    }
  ]
}
```

There is a demo project linked from the README which is a basic Sapper template with the required now configuration.

Note for exported applications, `@now/static` will suffice.