# Zeit now: api requires json file from static-build step

Tags: vercel

I am writing a web app and trying to deploy it to Zeit's Now.

my `now.json` contains:

```
"builds": [
    {
      "src": "build.sh",
      "use": "@now/static-build",
      "config": { "distDir": "out" }
    },
    { "src": "api/download/index.ts", "use": "@now/node" }
  ],
```

in the `api/download/index.ts` I'm trying to import a json file from the `static-build` output:

```
import slugs from "../../out/data/slugs.json";
```

but I get `4:19 Cannot find module '../../out/data/slugs.json'.` in the logs. AFAIK, the `static-build` goes well.

Is there a way to import a file from `static-build`'s `distDir`?

**UPD**

I'd outline here what should be done to fix it: as Paulo pointed out I had to do both:

```
{
      "src": "api/download/index.ts",
      "use": "@now/node",
      "config": {
        "includeFiles": ["data/**"]
      }
    }
```

and in package.json:

```
"now-build": "<generate content of ./data>"
```

It seems that `now` is using separate dirs for every builder, so that's why `data` dir from the first builder was not available for the second builder.

Comment: there is a hint https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56460903/now-cli-deployment-doesnt-build-package-json-dependencies

Comment: `"config": { "includeFiles": ["data/**"]  }` didn't help

Comment: https://spectrum.chat/zeit/now/import-generated-json-file-from-api-lambda~579fa70e-343d-4f0b-9d4f-cab625f5482e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [configuration](https://zeit.co/docs/v2/deployments/builders/overview#including-additional-files) you should have this:

```
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "api/download/index.ts",
      "use": "@now/node",
      "config": {
        "includeFiles": [
          "out/data/**"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
```

However, you need to make sure this file is available to your lambda. If it is generated then you could use `"now-build"` script in your `package.json` to create it.

With the information above, I think you should do the following:

```
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "api/download/index.ts",
      "use": "@now/node",
      "config": {
        "includeFiles": [
          "json/**"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
```

Create a new folder called `json` and move the needed files to it. Remember that the `includeFiles` configuration is relative to the root of your project (where `now.json` lives by default).

Comment: Thank you, Paulo. I gave it a try but it seems like it didn't help. Not sure what I'm missing.